# Abstract class methods implementation with subclasses of an other base class

Tags: c++

I am trying to define an interface  called "Algorithm" which has a pure virtual method insertData(InputData* input).

The implementation of the interface is called "Algorithm1" and i want to implement method "insertData" using as a parameter "SpecificData" which is a child of "InputData" class.

Is it possible without type casting?

Obviously with this code i get an error from the compiler that the virtual function  "insertData" is pure within "Algorithm1".

```
class Algorithm{
public:
    virtual ~Algorithm();
    virtual void insertData(InputData* input) = 0;
};

class Algorithm1 : public Algorithm{
public:    
    Algorithm1();
    virtual ~Algorithm1();

    void insertData(SpecificData* input){ 
    input.getID(); 
    input.getAdditionalNumbers;
    /*Process input information etc.*/ };
};

class InputData{
public: 
    void setID(int id){ this->id = id; }
    int getID(){ return id;};
private:
    int id;
};

class SpecifiData : public InputData{
public:
    list<int> getAdditionalNumbers(){/*Return various Numbers*/};
private:
    list<int> extraInfo;
};

void main(){
    SpecificData* data = new SpecificData();
    Algorithm* alg = new Algorithm1();
    alg->insertData(data);
}
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that doing it this way will always need a cast.

Comment: see Item 33: Avoid hiding inherited names from "Effective C++" book http://nova.polymtl.ca/~simark/Eff/Effective/0321334876/ch06lev1sec2.html

Answer (score 1):

For `insertData` to be the same function (rather than "hiding" the original `insertData`, you need the two functions to have the same arguments (and same return type).

The whole idea of interfaces using virtual functions is that "they appear the same from the outside". You should be able to build a list of objects, and perform the same operation with the same input data for all of the objects in the list.

If you are breaking that principle, you are "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't make sense.
Think about the following scenario - you have a container (vector/set w/e) of `Algorithm*` type objects and a function that takes this container and a `InputData* in` as an input and then iterate over them and call `insertData(in)` on each of the objects in the container, this of course should work properly, but if one of the objects in your container is of type Algorithm1 what will happen then?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a typical example of "Factory Method" in design pattern term.

```
 class Algorithm
    {
        public:
            virtual ~Algorithm();
            virtual void insertData(InputData* input) = 0;
    };
    class InputData
    {
        public: 
            void setID(int id){ this->id = id; }
            int getID(){ return id;};
            virtual list<int> getAdditionalNumbers() = 0;
        private:
            int id;
    };
    class Algorithm1 : public Algorithm
    {
        public:    
            Algorithm1();
            virtual ~Algorithm1();
            void insertData(InputData* input){ 
            input.getID(); 
            input.getAdditionalNumbers;
            /*Process input information etc.*/ };
    };
    class SpecifiData : public InputData
    {
        public:
            // implementation
            virtual list<int> getAdditionalNumbers(){/*Return various Numbers*/};
        private:
            list<int> extraInfo;
    };

    void main()
    {
            InputData* data = new SpecificData();
            Algorithm* alg = new Algorithm1();
            alg->insertData(data);
    }
```

Comment: You can construct two abstract base class: Algorithm and InputData, then, derives many classes as your will, but remember to implement the pure virtual functions which act as interface. Then, you can use the two class family just by the pointer or reference of their base classes and get the polymorphic.

Comment: Where is your factory method?

Comment: Perhaps I made a mistake... I may misunderstanding the meaning of the term "Factory Method"